# How to set AppBarCommand align to left in WinJS 4?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, winjs

some tutorials said, set section to "selection' then align will be left to right.

but it not works for me.

how to set AppBarCommand align to left in WinJS 4?

Comment: it looks only work in windows 8.1, any solution for windows 10 universal app ?

Answer (score 0):

On your AppBar, you can set its style to have a direction of rtl:

```
#AppBar {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Does that achieve the effect you are looking for?

Comment: not work on Windows 8.1 Universal & WInodws Universal